How to start a screen session from entrypoint shell script, and make it persist?
I am starting a screen session in my entrypoint shell script in docker, then log the output of screen -list to a file.
#!/bin/bash

screen -S my_screen -dm bash -c 'cd project && npm run start'

screen -list > scr_list.log

Then I connect to the docker container and see the resulting log.
here is a screen on: 
        14.my_screen      (12/18/24 17:55:29)     (Detached) 
1 Socket in /run/screen/S-root.

But when I manually run screen -list after connecting, it outputs:
No Sockets found in /run/screen/S-root.

Using the same user (whoami): root
I currently have multiple screen services running inside the container and I manually restart individual ones from time to time whenever I make some changes in the container
Any ideas what could be the issue please?

I figured out the issue: npm was not found.
Using read -p to pause the script and found out eventually that screen was persisting, but got terminated.
Update
To add node and npm to your $PATH variable, without needing to know the version number, use:
source /root/.nvm/nvm.sh

Original solution
By running which npm I found the path to my npm installation (version), then added it to the $PATH in my script.
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/npm

(folder in which npm executable is located)
